# ASP.NET Core IIS Deployment Issue aspnet-prerendering

Tags: npm, asp.net-core

I am having an issue deploying an ASP.NET Core app with Angular2 to IIS.

Steps so far -

- Created a starter Angular2 asp.net core project with aspnetcore-spa generator following [this](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/05/02/angular2-react-knockout-apps-on-aspnet-core/)
- Played around with some angular code and was able to debug in VS2015 as well as command line.  At this point the code is running
- Got IIS setup following [this](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html)
- Using VS2015 published to a folder.  Created a new IIS app and pointed to that folder.
- Point the browser and get an error

An error occurred while processing your request.

Log file shows

> fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[0]
>         An unhandled exception has occurred: Call to Node module failed with error: To use prerendering, you must install the 'aspnet-prerendering' NPM package.
>   System.Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: To use prerendering, you must install the 'aspnet-prerendering' NPM package.

The node_module folder with aspnet-prerendering is in the output folder.

One last thing to test that IIS is working, I created a basic project from VS template for .NET core and was able to get IIS working for a basic application.  No npm dependencies.

Thanks for any direction on this.

Comment: After more digging and trying a bunch of things - I eventually set my credentials for the app pool and it worked.  I thought I had tried it earlier without success, but might have been a combination with something else I did.  I was also able to use LocalSystem - but not ApplicationPoolIdentity.  Just for fun, I also renamed the aspnet-prerendering folder in node_modules in the output folder, which broke it even when running under my user (thought it might have been a path thing).  Security rights is wide open in the output folder, so not sure at this point, but must be a security thing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and after a few hours of unsuccsessfull attempts to resolve the error I created a new ASP.NET Core Web Application from VS2015 templates and just copied all .json and webpack config files, both ClientApp and typings folders into it. Also I updated Views folder from my project. I didn't replace web.config (I think web.config may cause the problem, but I'm not sure). After these actions everything seems to be working properly.

Also, I added `<TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>` to my .xproj file because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38478251/aspnetcore-spa-webpack-when-used-in-separate-project-builds-unwanted-js-file) problem.